# Custom font for mails in Gmail wanted without canned response

Tags: gmail

I would love to use a custom font (e.g. [Raleway](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway)) for all my e-mails. I read [an article](http://getyourtips.com/add-custom-fonts-in-gmail/) that explains on how to prepare a canned response and the signature. This works well using a canned response. But I have to select the canned response for every e-mail. I was wondering if there is a solution where I can just start typing.

Related: [Setting the default font/text size for Gmail messages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12713/setting-the-default-font-text-size-for-gmail-messages)

Comment: You can't use just _any_ font; only those Gmail provides. If you want to use something else you'll likely need to use a third-party email client.

Comment: In addition to @ale's comment, note that if your email recipient doesn't have Raleway installed on their own computer, I think that they'll see your email with a different font that they do have installed.