# How do I easily change the font colour in Gmail compose?

Tags: gmail, javascript, html

I often email responses inline to questions. In order to differentiate my response, I like to give them a colour.
This is quite onerous in Gmail, with about 3 clicks to get a colour applied.
I would love a *keyboard shortcut* **or** *a browser bar on click JavaScript hack* to do this... so question is, how to figure this out.

1. Javascript edit the HTML by adding the `<font>` tag around the selected words
   `<font color="#ff9900">The words to be changed</font>`

   Maybe using the `.wrap()` function - but difficult to work out the selector for some selected text
   This could be done with a browser extension. I use Chrome.
2. Track the Gmail function that fires when the colour is selected in the Text Styling menu

   - How to track a function in JavaScript?
     Hmmm stuck too. Then set it off with a keyboard shortcut somehow?
3. ??

I use Chrome and Brave browser - both same Chromium architecture.
Some sort of browser extension is probably the best.
But a Workspace Add-on might work too, just smaller user group maybe.
Ideally avoid using tampermonkey as difficult to implement.

A possible answer here:
Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393922/javascript-replace-selection-all-browsers by @tim-down

Getting close, but needs a tweak :

```
function wrapSelection(wrapSt, wrapEd, selectInserted) {
   var sel, range, fragment;

   if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
   // IE 9 and other non-IE browsers
   sel = window.getSelection();

   // Test that the Selection object contains at least one Range
   if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
     // Get the first Range (only Firefox supports more than one)
  range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  range.deleteContents();

  // Create a DocumentFragment to wrap existing selection
  // Need to test for the existence of range.createContextualFragment
  // because it's non-standard and IE 9 does not support it
  if (range.createContextualFragment) {
    fragment = range.createContextualFragment(wrapSt + sel.anchorNode.textContent + wrapEd);
  } else {
    // In IE 9 we need to use innerHTML of a temporary element
    var div = document.createElement("div"),
      child;
    div.innerHTML = wrapSt + sel.anchorNode.textContent + wrapEd;
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    while ((child = div.firstChild)) {
      fragment.appendChild(child);
    }
  }
  var firstInsertedNode = fragment.firstChild;
  var lastInsertedNode = fragment.lastChild;
  range.insertNode(fragment);
  if (selectInserted) {
    if (firstInsertedNode) {
      range.setStartBefore(firstInsertedNode);
      range.setEndAfter(lastInsertedNode);
    }
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
}
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
// IE 8 and below
range = document.selection.createRange();
range.pasteHTML(wrapSt + sel.anchorNode.textContent + wrapEd);
 }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/craiglambie/0em6wkz4/23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Gmail Built-In Features

### Defaulf format style

By changing the default format style there is no need to use userscripts or Gmail add-ons. Ref. [Formatting, fonts, and colors](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8260?hl=en).

1. Click on **Settings**  (gear button) > **See all settings**
2. In the **General** tab, go to **Default text style** section. Change the text format to be used by default when composing a new message.
3. Click **Save changes**

The above option might work while you only need to reply to messages that have not used the same text style as one that you choose as your default style and when not having to reply to a message that already have include inline comments with your default text style as when having to several back and forth over the same original message. In such case it might still convenient to have a quick way to change the text style.

#### Built in Gmail keyboard shortcuts

To open the on screen keyboards shortcuts guide, while viweing the Inbox or another view, except when composing a message press ?.

Help article: [Keyboard shortcuts for Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en)

Unfortunately the Formatting Text keyboard shortcuts doesn't include a shortcut to change the text color.

Note: The **Advanced** tab from Gmail **Settings** > **Advanced** has an option to enable **Keyboard Shortcuts**. Once enabling this option the **Keyboard Shortcuts** tab is added to the Gmail **Settings** but this only allows to change a predefined list of key mapping commands that, as March 2023, doesn't include changing the text style.

#### Templates

Gmail has a "hidden" feature (apparently it's not possible to find it searching from https://support.google.com/mail) called **Templates**. It allow to insert pre-written texts with a couple of clicks. It's not very different from the clicks required to change the text color, but might be worthy to learn about it as it might open other possibilities to optimize the overal composing process. This feature should be enabled in the same way that **Keyboard Shortcuts**, as explained above. For details see any of the following official help resorces for end-users:

- [Send a prewritten reply](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9259856?hl=en#reply-templates&zippy=%2Clearn-how)
- [Tips for sending email](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/11339703?hl=en#send)

#### Customized Layouts

If you are using a Workspace account, you might use customized layouts. See
[Create branded emails with customized layouts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10960345?hl=en)

## Chrome

### Developers Tools

#### Keyboard Shortcuts

When using Chrome, someone might think to use the Chrome Developers Tools keyboard shortcuts to open the Elements.Style pane and change the color attribute, but this doesn't look to be a time saver when the focus is  composing an email message.

Anyway, for me, the keyboard shortcut to open the **elements pane** is <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. For other options see [Keyboard shortcuts for opening DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/shortcuts/#global).

Additional you might use the keyboard to handle the Styles pane. For details see [Styles pane keyboard shortcuts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/shortcuts/#styles)

### Bookmarklets / Userscripts

Nowadays bookmarklets are off-topic in Web Applications. We might say that userscripts also are off-topic as well than software recommendations. Below there are some Q&A from sister sites:

#### Stack Overflow

- [Adding a custom keyboard shortcut using userscript to Chrome with Tampermonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13362028/1595451) from 2012
- [tampermonkey script unable to change css](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41498939/1595451) from 2017
- [Gmail extension/gadget API - how to add a button to the compose toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8689905/1595451) from 2011

## Add-ons and third-party software

Nowadays software recommendations are off-topic in Web Applications. Below there are some Q&A from sister sites:

#### Software Recommendations

- [Compose email in Gmail and edit HTML: is there a browser addon for this?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/46124/14228)

## Related

Related Q&A from this site

- [Setting the default font/text size for Gmail messages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/12713/88163)

Comment: Markup is great! That works for me! Something else to tweak :)